# What is set_opfunc?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal, lua, terminal-buffer

I'm configuring [toggleterm.nvim](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim), and in particular I'm putting this keybinding in my config file, as suggested by the plugin author [here](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#sending-lines-to-the-terminal):

```lua
-- Send motion to terminal
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>im", function()
  set_opfunc(function(motion_type)
    require("toggleterm").send_lines_to_terminal(motion_type, false, { args = vim.v.count })
  end)
  vim.api.nvim_feedkeys("g@", "n", false)
end)
```

My understanding is that `<leader>imw` should send a word to the terminal.

But when I issue `<leader>im` I get:

```
E5108: Error executing lua: .../USERNAME/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/config/toggleterm.lua:83: attempt to call global 'set_opfunc' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    .../USERNAME/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/config/toggleterm.lua:83: in function <.../USERNAME/.config/nvim/lua/plugins/config/toggleterm.lua:82>
```

Comment: FWIW, in Vim you would do something like `:set opfunc=functionName`

Comment: See :h 'opfunc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_opfunc` need to be defined first:

```lua
local set_opfunc = vim.fn[vim.api.nvim_exec([[
  func s:set_opfunc(val)
    let &opfunc = a:val
  endfunc
  echon get(function('s:set_opfunc'), 'name')
]], true)]
-- Send motion to terminal
vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>im", function()
  set_opfunc(function(motion_type)
    require("toggleterm").send_lines_to_terminal(motion_type, false, { args = vim.v.count })
  end)
  vim.api.nvim_feedkeys("g@", "n", false)
end)
```

See [this post](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/14157#issuecomment-1320787927) for more information.